# Angularstrap : How to get the popover element?

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

Thanks for your support in advance. I am new to Angularstrap and I am using the popover directive in my application. I need to get the popover element so that I can make it resizable. I have tried jquery traversing to get the element as well as data(popover) with no success. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Please let me know.

Regards,
Sam

Answer (score 1):

are you using angular-ui?

If so,
The element content can be get by angular.element('.popover-content') and you can set the width with 
angular.element('.popover-content').css('width','200px')

Comment: Thanks. I am using Angular-Strap